# JPA with eclipse link resultlist iterates to infinity

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

My 
Named query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "EmsDetails.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM EmsDetails e")
```

---

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EmsDetailsDTO.class);
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Employee_Mangement_SystemPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();


    public List<EmsDetails> getAllEMSDetails() {
        List<EmsDetails> emsDetails = em.createNamedQuery("EmsDetails.findAll").getResultList();
        logger.info(emsDetails.size());
        for(EmsDetails e : emsDetails){
            logger.info(e.getAddress());
        }

        return getAllEMSDetails();
    }

    public boolean addEmployee(EmsDetails detail){
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(detail);
        tx.commit();
        return true;        
    }

    public void closeEM(){
        em.close();
        emf.close();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EmsDetailsDTO e = new EmsDetailsDTO();
        e.getAllEMSDetails();
    }
```

---

Result:

```
4:55:36,660  INFO EmsDetailsDTO:28 - 1
14:55:36,670  INFO EmsDetailsDTO:30 - I 
14:55:36,670  INFO EmsDetailsDTO:28 - 1
14:55:36,670  INFO EmsDetailsDTO:30 - I 
14:55:36,670  INFO EmsDetailsDTO:28 - 1
14:55:36,670  INFO EmsDetailsDTO:30 - I
```

The result loops to infinity when using JPA (eclipselink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, List does not iterate to infinity. As you see from the logs, also `logger.info(emsDetails.size())`, which is outside of for loop is executed again and again.

Reason is that in the end of getAllEMSDetails method is call to getAllEMSDetails. It calls itself. So instead current return statement:

```
return getAllEMSDetails();
```

following works better:

```
return emsDetails;
```